# Download link for exe files results in "Not Found" error

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, razor-pages

I have an ASP.NET Core Razor Pages application and want to add a link which downloads an `exe` file when clicked. Therefore, I added the following code to my `Startup` class.

***Startup.cs***

```
app.UseStaticFiles();
app.UseStaticFiles(new StaticFileOptions
{
    FileProvider = new PhysicalFileProvider(Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), "folder1")),
    RequestPath = "/folder1"
});
var provider = new FileExtensionContentTypeProvider();
provider.Mappings.Add(".exe", "application/octect-stream");
app.UseStaticFiles(new StaticFileOptions
{
    ContentTypeProvider = provider
});
```

***Razor View***

```
<a id="installButton" href="https://mysite.net.au/folder1/install/setup.exe">Install</a>
```

When I click the link, I get the error below.

> Status Code: 404; Not Found

I have also tried using `application/vnd.microsoft.portable-executable` as the MIME type, but got the same error.

**UPDATE #1:**
I am aware that this issue has already been posted - I did a lot of searching and reading before posting, but none of the suggested solutions fixed the problem. Hence I needed to post my exact code/situation.

**UPDATE #2**
There is no button to answer my question so I'll just provide it here:
The only way I could get this working was to add BOTH static file options.
Here is the code that worked:

```
var provider = new FileExtensionContentTypeProvider();
provider.Mappings.Add(".exe", "application/octect-stream");
app.UseStaticFiles(new StaticFileOptions
{
   FileProvider = new physicalFileProvider(Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), "folder1")),
   RequestPath = "/folder1",
   ServeUnknownFileTypes = true,
   DefaultContentType = "plain/text",
   ContentTypeProvider = provider
});
```

Comment: I read this post and tried both methods but I keep getting 404 not found. so frustrating - cannot see why it's not working.

Comment: You are right. This was not a duplicate.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I tested your code and found the problem. You have to combine the last two UseStaticFiles declarations into one.

```
app.UseStaticFiles();
var provider = new FileExtensionContentTypeProvider();
provider.Mappings.Add(".exe", "application/octect-stream");
app.UseStaticFiles(new StaticFileOptions
{
    FileProvider = new PhysicalFileProvider(Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), "static")),
    RequestPath = "/folder1",
    ContentTypeProvider = provider
});
```

Comment: thx volkmar. i tried this but it still fails. i've been downvoted as this question already has answers but it does not work for me, so I posted my exact code.